# crash by scrolling of the page

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I have a problem with scrolling in mobile Native App, 
I am using :
Java as language
Java Client 1.7.0
appium node 1.13.0
OS version Android
AND Appium Driver

and trying to scroll after enter the page "Profile", but some How the app crashes.

[image]

I am using the following Methode for scrolling:

```
public void scrollDown() {
    Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    // System.out.println("Dimension value = "+dimension);

    Double scrollHeightStart = dimension.getHeight() * 0.5;
    int scrollStart = scrollHeightStart.intValue();
    // System.out.println("Screen Height start Value="+scrollHeightStart);

    Double scrollHeightEnd = dimension.getHeight() * 0.2;
    int scrollEnd = scrollHeightEnd.intValue();
    // System.out.println("Scroll Start Value="+scrollHeightEnd);

    TouchAction touch = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
    touch.press(PointOption.point(0, scrollStart))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(0, scrollEnd))
            .release()
            .perform();
}
```

but after run the script by calling the Scroll Method get the following in Log :

```
..........
.......
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:18 VORM. utilities.Helper startAppiumServer
    INFO: utilities.Helper§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ Start Appium Server §§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§
    startAppiumServer: Before Test done
    [HTTP] Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use. Please make sure there is no other instance of this server running already.
    Fatal Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:4723
        at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1270:14)
        at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
        at doListen (net.js:1451:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:31 VORM. io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/khazinehdarllo/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/3.2.8/cglib-3.2.8.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:31 VORM. utilities.Helper getmMthodName
    INFO: utilities.Helper +++++++++++++++++++++ Start of Test Execution: Test Case TC_1296_ForgotPassword_FromChangePasswordScreen +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:37 VORM. screens.Welcome_Screen click_Login_Button
    INFO: screens.Welcome_ScreenWELCOME Screen: Login Button clicked successfully (OK)
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:47 VORM. screens.Login_Screen enter_Valid_Email
    INFO: screens.Login_ScreenREGISTRATION Screen: Email Field entered successfully (OK)
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:53 VORM. screens.Login_Screen enter_Valid_Password
    INFO: screens.Login_ScreenREGISTRATION Screen: Password Field entered successfully (OK)
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:54 VORM. screens.Login_Screen select_remainLoggedIn_CheckBox
    INFO: screens.Login_ScreenLOGIN Screen : RemainLoggedIn Checkbox selected successfully (OK)
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:55 VORM. screens.Login_Screen click_Login_Button
    INFO: screens.Login_ScreenLOGIN Screen : Login Button clicked successfully (OK)
    Juni 22, 2019 3:31:58 VORM. screens.SelectCity_Screen select_X
    INFO: screens.SelectCity_ScreenSELECT CITY Screen : City X clicked successfully (OK)
    Juni 22, 2019 3:32:01 VORM. screens.CommonObjects_InAll_Screen click_Profile_Icon
    INFO: screens.CommonObjects_InAll_ScreenCOMMON OBJECT Profile Icon : Profile Icon clicked successfully (OK)

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at utilities.PageActions.scrollDown(PageActions.java:308)
        at testScripts.login.errorHandling.Login_ErrorHandling_No_FTU_Tests.TC_1296_ForgotPassword_FromChangePasswordScreen(Login_ErrorHandling_No_FTU_Tests.java:119)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
        at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
        at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


    Juni 22, 2019 3:32:01 VORM. testScripts.BasicSetup stopApp
    INFO: testScripts.BasicSetupDestroying Test Environment
    Juni 22, 2019 3:32:01 VORM. testScripts.BasicSetup stopApp
    INFO: testScripts.BasicSetupStop App
    Juni 22, 2019 3:32:01 VORM. testScripts.BasicSetup stopApp
    INFO: testScripts.BasicSetup ===================== End of Test Execution ===========================

    ===============================================
    Default Suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================

    Juni 22, 2019 3:32:02 VORM. testScripts.login.errorHandling.Login_ErrorHandling_No_FTU_Tests stopAppiumServer
    INFO: testScripts.login.errorHandling.Login_ErrorHandling_No_FTU_TestsStop Appium Server
    Juni 22, 2019 3:32:02 VORM. testScripts.login.errorHandling.Login_ErrorHandling_No_FTU_Tests stopAppiumServer
    INFO: testScripts.login.errorHandling.Login_ErrorHandling_No_FTU_Tests===============================================
```

and .PageActions.scrollDown(PageActions.java:308) is in code in methode scrollDown:

Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();

My assumption is that the scroll view does not start from beginning of page
so i have first to switch to scroll view layout then I can scroll

I have the same View in Registration or login screen but first when I click on any other point inside the scrolView e.g. enter Email or Name, then I can scrollDown, but in this window (Profil) I can not

[image]
thanks for any Support

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found, by using UiAutomator and UiSelector scrolling works.

driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"<--your_resourceID-->"));"));